# Unable to connect to SQL shell server

Tags: windows, postgresql

Recently I've installed SQL Shell to run some SQL codes and the first thing that the shell shows is

[image: the following image]

Being a newbie in SQL, I have NO IDEA what to fill in in each option so I've spent many hours looking for the solution but every time I type in password, I get the following error

[image: click the link to see the image!]

I'd want to run the following code:

```
 CREATE TABLE flights (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    origin VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    destination VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    duration INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

to get some ideas of how the platform works, but the server connection process hinders my progress. Would anyone please provide a kind suggestion?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIfcg.png)

Comment: First I'd suggest putting the text from the images into code blocks so that people can immediately see what the issue is.

Comment: The stupid batch file the Enterprise DB Server creates is usually more confusing than helpful. Start a regular Windows command line and start `psql` from there. The error indicates that your Postgres server was setup with GSSAPI authentication (which is very unusual in Windows). This could means it's authenticating against an Active Directory (or LDAP) - you need to find out which password is needed there. Ask your DBA for the details

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I've put the full picture of the error that pops up and apparently I'm using MacBook for psql. Every time I type in 'psql' on my terminal, my computer can't recognise the comment (although the platform is already installed!) and what do you mean that there's authenticating against an Active Directory? The error always says that the terminal can't read load the server typed in.